# NameError 'unicode' not defined, this error occurs when I use save function in django model

Tags: python, html, css, django, python-3.x

Error log from the output :

```
NameError at /admin/todo/todomodel/add/
name 'unicode' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/todo/todomodel/add/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Few more details about the system and exception :

Exception Location: `C:\Users\PEE TEE\Desktop\ToDoApp\lib\site-packages\slugify.py in slugify, line 24`

Python Executable:  `C:\Users\PEE TEE\Desktop\ToDoApp\Scripts\python.exe`

Python Version: `3.7.6`

Python Path:
`['C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\src',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\pee tee\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\pee tee\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp',
 'C:\\Users\\PEE TEE\\Desktop\\ToDoApp\\lib\\site-packages']`

Server time:    Tue, 4 Feb 2020 03:03:37 +0000

And this is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from slugify import slugify
# Create your models here.

class ToDoModel(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   what_todo = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Event to be done")
   date_todo = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False) 
   slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.what_todo and not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.what_todo)
        return super(ToDoModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.what_todo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using some code related to Python 2, Python 3 renamed the `unicode` type to `str`.
See details in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

correct your slugify code

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.what_todo)
    return super(ToDoModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed the wrong package... You installed slugify while the relevant package is called python-slugify. One is not compatible with python3.

```
pip3 uninstall slugify
pip3 install python-slugify
```